# Exiting from a Makefile based on the state of two shell variables

Tags: if-statement, makefile, gnu-make

During `make checksource`, `$CROSS_COMPILE` should be `"whatever"`.  If `$CROSS_COMPILE` is not set, `make` should throw an error and exit.

I have the following rule in my `Makefile`:

```
.PHONY: checksource

all: checksource default

checksource:
    $(if $(and $(ifeq ($(CROSS_COMPILE), whatever)), $(ifeq ($(VARIABLE),))), \
    ($(shell echo "Error! VARIABLE not defined!") \
     $(shell exit 2)))
```

Right now if `$CROSS_COMPILE` is set to whatever and `$VARIABLE` is undefined, the `make` doesn't exit.

`$CROSS_COMPILE`:

```
$> echo $CROSS_COMPILE
whatever
$>
```

`$VARIABLE` is not defined:

```
$> echo $VARIABLE
$>
```

I could use a nested `ifeq`, but I want to make it pretty (and learn a bit more about `Makefile` operations).

Answer (score 16):

There is no such thing as `$(ifeq)`. I still think you should do the check in the makefile itself, not as one of the targets:

```
ifeq ($(CROSS_COMPILE),whatever)
ifeq ($(VARIABLE),)
$(error Variables not set correctly.)
endif
endif
```

And if you're set on avoiding nested `ifeq`:

```
ifeq ($(or $(subst whatever,,$(CROSS_COMPILE)),$(VARIABLE)),)
$(error Variables not set correctly.)
endif
```

But I fail to see how that's an improvement. If you want to do it in a target, just use the shell and don't bother with make functions:

```
checksource:
    @if [ "$(CROSS_COMPILE)" = whatever -a -z "$(VARIABLE)" ]; then \
        echo "Error: Variables not set correctly"; exit 2; \
    else true; fi
```

I'd still go with the first option, because you can stop make before it `stat` s all the files names in `Makefile` and decides to start executing `checksource`.

Answer (score 3):

Doing it in make is always better than using the shell (whether via `$(shell)` or a recipe). If you do do the check in a recipe, then it means that the Makefile can contain other targets that do not need this particular assert.

```
assert = $(if $(filter whatever,${CROSS_COMPILE}),$(if ${VARIABLE},,$(error Urk! Variable problem)))

checksource:
        ${assert}some shell commands...
```

P.S. If you ran your original make with `--warn-undefined-variables` you may have got some clue why your macros were not expanding properly:

```
$ make -f 1.mak CROSS_COMPILE=whatever --warn-undefined-variables
1.mak:6: warning: undefined variable `ifeq (whatever, whatever)'
make: *** No rule to make target `default', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```